# Swift: How to reset simulator by running shell command

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to reset the simulator after every test.
I found the best way to do it, is to execute

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```

but I don't know how to add a shell command in a swift file to execute it.

I tried

```
import Foundation
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
  }
```

But got an error, Process u\identifier not found
Please help.
I am trying to reset the simulators after each test.

Can I uninstall a particular application from the simulator from the command line? or any other way between each test, in the tearDown()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it with [SBTUITestTunnel](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel).
I chose to use this framework as I had also had to communicate between the testing application and my actual application to configure testing states.

With SBTUITestTunnel implemented you can specify launch options, the one you require is SBTUITunneledApplicationLaunchOptionResetFilesystem.

```
app.launchTunnel(withOptions: [SBTUITunneledApplicationLaunchOptionResetFilesystem]) {
 // do additional setup before the app launches
 // i.e. prepare stub request, start monitoring requests 
}
```

I would recommend having a look at SBTUITestTunnel as it will allow you to do some other very powerful things.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, but its a workaround. I will try to do it through shell commands first and if all fails, explore the new framework.

Comment: If you need to run specific shell commands from the host running the tests you might consider [SBTUITestTunnelHost](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnelHost) which is another tool that I developed along SBTUItestTunnel. It allows to run arbitrary shell commands from the UI Test target.

Comment: I added a prebuild step to my test. Go to Edit Scheme-> Click triangle next to Test -> + and add pre build step -> xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.XYZ.client.main

Comment: I don't believe that execute on a test by test basis. Won't it only execute on the initial run of the tests?

Your original question stated "reset the simulator after every test.".